# Semipermeable swimming nose clips

Tags: equipment, swimming

Is there a solution against nose aches after a lot of swimming?

maybe nose clips, that only let you breathe out and close when you breathe in?

Comment: What's the source of the nose aches?

Comment: too much chlorine

Answer (score 3):

You can buy nose clips on Amazon, a lot of swimmers use them. I don't know what they are like but from what I read some people use them if they have allergies to chemicals in a pool. That could be the problem you are having?

Here is an [excerpt from a good article](http://www.enjoy-swimming.com/nose-clips.html) on the pros and cons of using a nose clip.

**Advantages:**

> If your nose is allergic to pool chemicals (e.g. chlorine), a clip
>   might be the solution to keep those chemicals out.

**Drawbacks:**

> Breathing is less efficient because the nose is shut down and the
>   overall physical efficiency in the water decreases. You have a greater
>   tendency to hold your breath if you wear a nose plug. Holding your
>   breath should be avoided as it is better to exhale continuously in the
>   water because it keeps the body more relaxed and the stroke more
>   fluid. Water might become trapped in the nose and generate snot that
>   can't evacuate. That was the case for me and my nose was regularly
>   obstructed after a swim practice where I had used a clip.

This is an [excerpt from an article](http://www.livestrong.com/article/387496-swimming-and-nasal-congestion/) talks about the reasons why you could have an aching nose after swimming.

> **Breathing:**
>
> Proper breathing during swimming is essential to help reduce nasal
>   congestion and discomfort. If you get water in your nose while
>   swimming, try to continually exhale slowly through your nose. When you
>   raise your head to breathe, do it quickly between strokes. This may
>   feel odd in the beginning, but with practice you will become
>   accustomed to this type of breathing. The pressure of the air that you
>   exhale prevents water from entering your nose.
>
> **Allergies:**
>
> Both chlorine and bromine are gases in the halogen family of
>   chemicals. Both chemicals are used to sanitize water. Chlorine is less
>   expensive and is often used in public pools. Unlike bromine, chlorine
>   can tolerate sunlight and is most often used in outdoor facilities.
>   Bromine is used for hot tubs and spas because it is easily destroyed
>   by sunlight. Bromine does not have the chemical smell of chlorine,
>   which acts as irritant that can result in nasal congestion. Both
>   chemicals can cause respiratory and skin reactions. They are absorbed
>   through your skin, so showering off as soon as you can after leaving
>   the pool is important.
>
> **Infections:**
>
> Inhaled water that lodges in your sinus cavities can cause irritation
>   and infection. This condition is known as sinusitis and nasal
>   congestion is one of the first symptoms. You are more likely to get an
>   infection from ocean or lake water because it is not sanitized and is
>   filled with living organisms. If your nasal congestion is accompanied
>   by headache, body aches and fever, see your health care provider for
>   proper treatment.

Comment: In case these links die, what are the pros and cons and what are the reasons for an aching nose after swimming?

Comment: Ok I'll add them to the answer

Comment: @Ronan are you quoting all that? if so please make it clear, and that's kind of a lot text to copy/paste into an answer.

Comment: Use quotation marks? Yea I Was thinking that I could get rid of some of the less important stuff